# Make a list of a dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a list of the index of my dataframe so I can use it as the X values in a plot.
I'm also trying to make a list of the `rainfall` so I can use it as the Y values in a plot. The dataframe is `df` and the index column is `date`.

```
df=pd.read_csv(data_source, sep=',', comment='#', header=None, names=['station', 'date', 'T_gem', 'T_min', 'T_max', 'rainfall'], parse_dates=[1])
df = df.set_index(['date'])
january = df.loc['2021-01-01':'2021-01-31']
```

I've tried using `january = df.loc['2021-01-01':'2021-01-31', 'date']` but that raises a KeyError because I think it cannot find the column `date` as it is an index.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
january_df = df['2021-01-01':'2021-01-31']
```

After this, you can use the proposed solution.

```
january_df['rainfall'].plot()
```

You don't have to reset the index and create a list.

Comment: I have 10 years worth of rainfall data so january 2021 aren't the first 31 rows. How can I filter on the rainfall of january only? The `date` column is of the datatype datetime